# Unity : pool game emulator : The cue ball didn't bounce back as expected; instead, it continued to travel along the table's edge

Tags: unity-game-engine

The cue ball, after colliding with the table edge, didn't bounce back as expected; instead, it continued to travel along the table's rail, closely hugging its edge.

**emulation**
[image: emulation]

The following are the physical materials of the edge and the ball:

**ball physical material**
[image: ball physical material]

**edge physical material**
[image: edge physical material]

I have tried adjusting various coefficients, but it may either result in excessive elasticity or the ball still continuing to travel along the table's edge.

The following is the C# code which provide the velocity and direction of cue ball

```cs
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CueBallController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string cueball_position_Path = "D:/Unity Project/testtest/Assets/Resources/cueball_position.json";
    private string HitParams_Path = "D:/Unity Project/testtest/Assets/Resources/HitParams.json";

    [System.Serializable]
    public class HitParams
    {
        public float HitSpeed;
        public Vector3 HitDirection;
    }

    HitParams LasthitParams;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    public float stationaryThreshold = 0.01f;
    private bool allBallsStationary = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        LoadInitialPosition(cueball_position_Path);
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        LasthitParams = new HitParams();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        allBallsStationary = CheckIfAllBallsAreStationary();

        if (allBallsStationary)
        {
            // Load initial parameters from JSON file
            HitParams newHitParams = LoadHitParams(HitParams_Path);

            if (newHitParams != null && (newHitParams.HitSpeed != LasthitParams.HitSpeed || newHitParams.HitDirection != LasthitParams.HitDirection))
            {
                // Normalize the initial direction and apply the initial speed
                Vector3 hitVelocity = newHitParams.HitDirection.normalized * newHitParams.HitSpeed;

                StartCoroutine(MoveWithDelay(2.0f, hitVelocity));

                LasthitParams = newHitParams;
            }
        }
    }

    private void LoadInitialPosition(string path)
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
            Vector3 position = JsonUtility.FromJson<Vector3>(json);
            transform.position = position;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("JSON file not found at: " + path);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveWithDelay(float delay, Vector3 hitVelocity)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

        rb.velocity = hitVelocity;
    }

    private HitParams LoadHitParams(string path)
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
            HitParams loadedHitParams = JsonUtility.FromJson<HitParams>(json);
            return loadedHitParams;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("JSON file not found at: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private bool CheckIfAllBallsAreStationary()
    {
        GameObject[] balls = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Ball");
        float angularThreshold = 0.01f;

        foreach (GameObject ball in balls)
        {
            Rigidbody ballRigidbody = ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

            if (ballRigidbody != null &&
                (ballRigidbody.velocity.magnitude > stationaryThreshold ||
                ballRigidbody.angularVelocity.magnitude > angularThreshold))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (!rb.IsSleeping()) return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Comment: @Rob I think this may be related to Unity's C# program, so I came here to ask.

Comment: Then you need to supply a [mcve] here, within your question.

Comment: @Fattie He didn't supply any code (he edited code in after my post). Unless he supplies code, which is required ([mcve]), it appears he is only trying to configure Unity. That makes it off topic. It matters not how many other questions are asked.

Comment: Note that the "cue ball" is the white one. The red one is known as the "object ball".

Comment: Rob, by all means "I don't own SO" :)   But there are an ocean of questions about software (in general) and on SO (in particular) that have nothing at all to do with "lines of code". This applies to both "real" programming and nonsense like building iOS apps, moving buttons around.  What you describe as "Configuring _ _ _" amounts to perhaps a third? (maybe more) of all questions on SO.  There are very, very few "real" programming questions on SO, the overwhelming majority is just trash about moving buttons around in "droid, web, ios, unity" - configuring as you put it. Take it as you will!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has to do with the default physics configuration. Low velocity impacts are treated as inelastic collisions and the bounce is ignored (even if you set it up in your physics material). This is done to help calm down the physics simulation when you have a pile of slow moving rigid bodies all colliding with each other.

For 3D physics you need to lower the [`Bounce Threshold`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-bounceThreshold.html) under `Edit->Project Settings->Physics`

For 2D physcis you need to lower the [`velocityThreshold`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D-velocityThreshold.html) under `Edit->Project Settings->Physics 2D`

Don't make the value too low, something like 0.1 should be enough.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried to make the modifications and it's working properly now. I am really grateful for your help！！

Comment: @Demons yes, that's the answer in this case. Be aware that PhysX, and any "game physics" engine, is very much not meant to be "perfect", it's not a "scientific simulation". It's completely commonplace that when you're working on some particular rig, some scene idea, PhysX is "not enough" for what you're trying to do. (Indeed, note that PhysX has nothing at all to do with soft body physics or fluids, for that you have to get in to pybullet.org or some other system.) in PhysX, there are a LOT of subtle settings you'll have to get in to, to become expert with it! Enjoy

Comment: @Fattie Got it! Thank you for sharing. This is my first time encountering a physics engine and I have been struggling with this issue for a long time. Thank you for your patient guidance, it has been very helpful to me.